# Copy a SageMaker Notebook to SageMaker Studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

My colleague made a notebook in SageMaker but I want to copy that notebook into SageMaker Studio so that future collaborations and changes are smoother.
From Studio, I can't see anything that relates it to SageMaker classic.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a single notebook download the notebook from Jupyter in the notebook instance (in Jupyter File menu), then upload it to Studio notebooks.
If it's many notebooks, from the notebook instance open a terminal to copy them to S3, the in Studio, copy from S3 to the Studio storage.
`aws s3 cp /tmp/my_notebook s3://my_bucket/my_notebook`
`aws s3 cp s3://my_bucket/my_notebook /tmp/my_notebook`

Answer (score 0):

A general approach to copy a notebook from a SageMaker Notebook Instance to SageMaker Studio:

1. Export the Notebook from SageMaker instance:
   Click on File -> Download as -> Notebook (.ipynb).
2. Upload to SageMaker Studio:
   Open SageMaker Studio.
   Upload the downloaded .ipynb file to a location in your Studio environment.

However you can first copy your notebook instance into a S3 bucket using

```
aws s3 cp /path/to/my_notebook s3://my_bucket/my_notebook
```

This needs to be run in terminal window of your notebook instance and then go to your notebook studio and open a terminal and copy them back from the S3 bucket

```
aws s3 cp s3://my_bucket/my_notebook .
```